# Django Rest Framework Serializer Model Custom Method with parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible for a serializer field to use a model's custom method with parameters as its source? Something like:

models.py

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def sample_method(self, param):
        if param == 'x':
            return 1
        elif param == 'y':
            return 0
```

serializers.py

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x = # serializer field that returns sample_method custom method with a parameter of 'x'
    y = # serializer field that returns sample_method custom method with a parameter of 'y'

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('x', 'y')
```

It should return as a response something similar to:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try using the [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as follows if the values `x` and `y` are static:

#### Models

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def sample_method(self, param):
        if param == 'x':
            return 1
        elif param == 'y':
            return 0
```

#### Serializers

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x = SerializerMethodField()
    y = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('x', 'y')

    def get_x(self, obj):
        return obj.sample_method('x')

    def get_y(self, obj):
        return obj.sample_method('y')
```

Another possible way of doing this is to create two separate properties (that explicitly call the `sample_method` with the value `x` or `y`) on your model itself and simply use the names as fields in your serializer. For example:

#### Models

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def sample_method(self, param):
        if param == 'x':
            return 1
        elif param == 'y':
            return 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.sample_method('x')

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.sample_method('y')
```

#### Serializers

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('x', 'y')
```

Comment: Actually, is there a way to put parameters on the actualy Serializer Method Field attribute?

Comment: Not Really, Are the values `x` or `y` dynamic ? Are these values stored somewhere, If they are then you may try retrieving the values inside the method instead of passing it to the method.

Comment: Is that so, then I'll have to go with your first suggestion, I'm actually trying to override the values on the sample_method to apply the DRY principle on my custom methods. Because I have three custom model methods that's a little bit identical to each other and I can just cut it to one, and just have parameters